# Insert records in table based on 'master' record in same table

Tags: sql, oracle, merge

I have one table, e.g. pricerules, that have stored special prices by article for customers. Now I want to sync the pricerules, based on an other user. Suppose I have this as dataset:

```
+---------------------------+
| user_id | prod_id | price |
+---------+---------+-------+
| 10      | 1       | 1     |
| 10      | 2       | 5     |
| 10      | 3       | 7     |
| 20      | 2       | 5     |
| 30      | 2       | 5     |
| 30      | 3       | 7     |
+---------+---------+-------+
```

Now I would like to update/insert the prices for several other users, based upon the prices of user 10. I already wrote the delete and update query, but I'm stuck with the insert query to insert the new rules that the other users don't have yet.

So effectively this would do the following inserts:

```
INSERT INTO pricerules 
(user_id, prod_id, price) 
VALUES 
(20, 1, 1), 
(20, 3, 7), 
(30, 1, 1);
```

Is there a way to do this in one query? I have been looking for `MINUS` to select the records that are not present for user 20, but I would have to execute a query for each user.

I thought maybe I could use `MERGE`.

I am using Oracle 10.1 ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were right. Merge is the way to go. Please try the following.

```
merge into pricerules p
using ( select t1.user_id, t2.prod_id, t2.price
   from 
   (select distinct user_id
   from pricerules
   where user_id <> 10) t1,
   (select distinct prod_id, price
   from pricerules
   where user_id = 10) t2
   ) t
on (p.user_id = t.user_id
   and p.prod_id = t.prod_id
   and p.price = t.price)
when not matched then 
   insert (user_id, prod_id, price) values (t.user_id, t.prod_id, t.price) ;
```

Comment: OP has asked it to be `based upon the prices of user 10`, so perhaps you need to add to subqry t1 `where user_id<>10` and to subqry t2 `where user_id=10`

Comment: Unfortunately this method doesn' seem to work too well when you also need to insert a primary key, using a sequence (using seq.nextval). The sequence will always be upped with +1.

Comment: Which field is filled by the sequence?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Oracle in a long while, so my syntax may be slightly off, but the general idea is:

```
INSERT INTO pricerules 
(user_id, prod_id, price) 
select 20 as user_id, 1 as prod_id, 1 as price from dual
union all
select 20, 3, 7 from dual
union all
select 30, 1, 1 from dual
```

Answer (score 0):

Quickly typed this together so I'm not sure if it's correct. But what I'm trying to do is to select all product id's from user 10 that the new user does not already have.

What's missing in your question is where the user_id's originate. You may want to join this with a user table so you can run it for all users.

```
insert into pricerules
   (user_id, prod_id, price)
   select &new_user_id
         ,prod_id
         ,price
     from pricerules p
    where user_id = 10
      and not exists (select 1
             from pricerules p2
            where p2.userid = &new_userid
              and p2.prod_id = p.prod_id)
```

Comment: I didn't want to complicate things any more, but actually there is a field "belongs_to_user_id" in the user table. So the new_user_id would be all a SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE belongs_to_user_id = 10. My struggle was exactly the same: I cannot find how to get that ID in for each user. So I was able to find price rules that the new user didn't have, but I didn't know the user_id. :-s